# Django Annotate - Can I used the fields created in annotate for another field created in annotate?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am calculating the sum of scores by dept and the number of users in each department in annotate like this:

```
queryset = Depts.objects.annotate(total_pts=Sum('userprofiles__user__activity_user__activity_category__pts'), total_users=Count('userprofiles', distinct=True)).order_by('-total_pts')
```

I also want to send back as part of the return data avg_score = total_pts / total_users.  Is there a way to add this into the annotate, or chain them together, or otherwise add this to the return queryset?

EDIT:

I tried to add in something like:

```
queryset = Depts.objects.annotate(total_pts=Sum('userprofiles__user__activity_user__activity_category__pts'), total_users=Count('userprofiles', distinct=True), avg_score=total_pts/total_users).order_by('-total_pts')
```

It errors out stating that total_pts is not defined.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with the current setup? Got error? What errors? Add a *minimal verifiable example* too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using F(), never quite understood how to use that before:

```
queryset = Depts.objects.annotate(total_pts=Sum('userprofiles__user__activity_user__activity_category__pts'), total_users=Count('userprofiles', distinct=True), avg_score=F('total_pts') / F('total_users')).order_by('-avg_score')
```